# How to monitoring to Azure Functions Exception

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-monitoring

I am watching Functions Exception with classic alert.

```
Conditions
Metric: Server exceptions >= 1 Count
```

Now I have to replace from Classic alert to Azure Monitor, but I don't know what condition to use.

How do I set it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new alerts are a little different from the classic alerts. Setting up a new alert requires three steps：

1. Define alert condition.
   Select alert target and alert criteria.
   [image]

[image]

Select server exceptions in the Signal type option.

2. Define alert details.
   This step defines the alert rule name and description and selects the severity.
3. Define action group.
   This step is used to notify your team via email and text messages and so on and the action group is reusable.

Comment: Thank you very much. Thanks to the screenshot, it was easy to set up.